# DynamoDB most efficient date type

Tags: date, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I see that DynamoDB is essentially limited to [three data types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html#DataModel.DataTypes): String, Number, and Binary.  That seems to leave two options for storing a date or timestamp:

- **String** of an 8601 date/time format or Unix timestamp
- **Number** of a Unix timestamp

I will need to 'sort' results by using this date/timestamp as a range key and using scanIndexForward.  Is it possible to say which approach would be more efficient?

Comment: I know this is a year old question, but did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 21):

I don't know that it's necessarily more efficient, but we have had good success using a Unix timestamp as range keys.    It's been fast (under 20ms latency, sometimes under 10ms) for queries and lets us sort "earliest to latest" or "latest to earliest" using the `scanIndexForward` flag.

The downside is that when looking at the raw tables it can be tough to compare two timestamps at a glance, but it's easy enough to convert a timestamp into a date-type in your language of choice.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a DescribeTable on one of my DynamoDB tables and noticed that DynamoDB itself stores the CreationDateTime of the table as a UNIX timestamp floating point number. I guess they did that for a reason.